# The Elder Scrolls Online Morrowind (PS4)

Tags: ps4, the-elder-scrolls-online

I bought the $59 version of this game for a friend and have a few questions.  Are the expansions from the original Xbox game (Bloodmoon and Tribunal) included in this version?  Or are there further purchases to be made?

As well, is it necessary for one to have an account with Elder Scrolls Online in order to play the game?  Or can the Morrowind content be accessed as a solo player without ever having an account with Elder Scrolls Online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing 2 versions of Morrowind.

The Elder Scrolls Online: Morrowind is an expansion pack from 2017 for The Elder Scrolls Online, the MMORPG released in 2014. the basic version does not stand alone and thus requires an Elder Scrolls Online game. The 59 $ version comes with the base game included, which means you don't already need an ESO account.

The Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind is the 3rd game in the Elder Scrolls franchise, a purely singleplayer RPG released in 2002. It has 2 expansions (Bloodmoon and Tribunal) and does not require any other game to be playable.

Comment: You're confusing things and mixing up facts as well. The 59$ version of the game includes the base game ("Tamriel Unlimited") and Morrowind even includes a new tutorial for new players/characters. There is no "aimed at high level players", because the whole game scales with your character.

Comment: @Mario I have taken into account your comment and made a couple of edits

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing a few things here – as mentioned – but there's a bit more to it.

**The Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind** is a classic RPG 15 years old now, which had two expansions called **Bloodmoon** and **Tribunal**.

**The Elder Scrolls Online** is a MMORPG originally launched in 2014 for PC/Mac and 2015 for consoles. It's a buy to play game with no forced subscription (other than being a member of PlayStation Plus or Xbox Gold respectively). You can start an optional subscription for full access to all DLC (and other benefits), but it's up to you. As an alternative you can buy DLC as you're used to for games such as *Skyrim*.

**The Elder Scrolls Online: Morrowind** is a so-called chapter (basically an expansion pack) released earlier this year, which expands the game world with the Island of Vvardenfell (same location as TES3, just 700 years earlier).

The 59$ retail (or online) version you've bought is basically the "full package": Your friend gets both **The Elder Scrolls Online: Tamriel Unlimited** and **The Elder Scrolls Online: Morrowind**. (Existing players can get a 40$ discounted "Upgrade".)

The whole game world scales with your character so your friend can experience the whole game – both the "old" regions on mainland Tamriels as well as Vvardenfell – right off the get go. There is no "aimed at high level players" except some "Veteran" geared content (like higher difficulty versions of Trials; ESO's equivalent of raids).